# Resize function for HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I managed to put together a dynamically resizing HTML5 Canvas but it has issues. For instance, it only scales the height, not the width too. My canvas has width of `900px` and height of `850px`. Another issue is that it enlarges the canvas too, way beyond it's defined width and height.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
  createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install();

  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  exportRoot = new lib.Hat_finale();

  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  stage.update();

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function resize() {
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  var ratio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
  var width = height * ratio;

  canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = height + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('load', resize, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 850px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="850" style="background-color:#ffffff"></canvas>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If I try what @havex said, changing the attributes like so: `canvas.width = width;` and `canvas.height = height;` instead of `canvas.style.width = width+'px';` and `canvas.style.height = height+'px';` what I get is a resizable box BUT NOT the animation. See picture for reference :

[image]

Comment: @halex It doesn't work, It only scales some sort of box but not the entire animation, see question update for reference photo.

Comment: @gamealchemist What do you mean by that ??

Comment: @gamealchemist Post an answer and if it's good and it works, you get the answer marked ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why that is happening because it's 4:30 in the morning and I haven't slept yet, but change these and it should work (you can remove the borders):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:#ffffff"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:900px;
  height:850px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

canvas { width: 900px; height: 850px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5z1zab/