# Image type color sticks to left on small screen

Tags: css, html

I have a site. [Please see this](http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=8). It works fine on large screen but when I see it on mobile, the color section is sticking to the left. Please advise me what should I do?

Comment: We don't have access to your localhost

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with this this below html will solve the issue

```
<input class="form-control center-block" name="colorpicker" onchange="hello(colorpicker.value);" style="width: 50px;" type="color">
```

Comment: Thankyou. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Is there any way to make the canvas image responsive?

Comment: you can make it by writing css media queries

Comment: check over here .>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445907/jquery-to-make-html5-canvas-responsive

Answer (score 1):

You input has a class `.form-control` and in bootstrap.css a css property `display:inline-block` to `.form-control` is applied only on screen larger then `768px` so when you resize to small screen `.form-control` gets `display:block` because of which its happening just add this a custom class to you input and this css.

```
input.custom_class{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the canvas image responsive?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this css for canvas in responsive:

```
canvas {
  border: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove class="form-control" if you don't want that to happen and style them separately. Its bootstrap's breakpoints doing this.